# Is there any chance that this set is contained in a reflexive Banach space?

Tags: convex-analysis, compactness, topological-vector-spaces, convex-hulls, reflexive-space

Let $(\mathcal X,\Sigma_X,p_X)$ be a probability space. Define the following set $S=\{ p : (\mathcal X,\Sigma_X,p)\text{ is a probability space, } p\ll p_X \}$ where $\ll$ denote absolute continuity. I equip this space with the total variation metric : $\| p-q \|=\sup_{A\in\Sigma_X} |p(A)-q(A)|$ (I am not too attached to that metric if something else would work better). I want to make statements on that space of the kind of the [Krein-Milman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem) on that set, I know it is not compact but following [another question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261494/a-compact-convex-set-is-the-closed-convex-hull-of-its-extreme-points) I think it could be enough for me to have that $S$ to be a topological subset of some reflexive TVS $E$, hence my question

> Is there a reflexive topological vector space $E$ such that $S$ is a topological subset of $E$.

---

I wonder if we have to add a condition that $p_X$ is atomic, if so I think the extreme points of $S$ may be something like $\{ 1_A : A\in\mathcal A \}$ where $\mathcal A$ are the atoms of $p_X$.

---

I think there is a problem with that, there is a chance that if $\mathcal X=[0,1]$, $\Sigma_X$ is the set of Borel subsets of $\mathcal X$ and $p_X$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ then $S$ doesn't have any extreme points right ? But having $S$ in a reflexive space would mean that $S$ is the closed convex hull of it's extreme points which it could not be. Am I wrong there ?

Answer (score 1):

To long for a comment.

Yes, if $S$ does not possess extremal points, it cannot be compact in any locally convex vector space topology (due to Krein-Milman).

It is also possible to apply Krein-Milman to the weak-* topology in duals of Banach spaces. I think in most cases, the set of probability measures is weak-* compact in the dual of $C_0(\mathcal X)$ (continuous functions on $\mathcal X$ vanishing at infinity). However, with your additional absolute continuity constraint you loose the weak-* closedness of the set.

Finally, if $p_X$ is atomic, your set $S$ should be isomorphic to a subset of (a weighted version of?) $\ell^1$, which is the dual of $c_0$ (convergent sequences with limit $0$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think in the first one you meant "it cannot be compact in any topology" instead right ? So without the absolutely continuous constraint, the extreme points exist, for instance if all $\{x\}$ are in $\Sigma_X$ for $x\in\mathcal X$, then they are the $\delta_x$ probability measures. I don't understand how I lose closedness since we can see the absolutely continuous condition as follow : Let $\mathcal A=\{ A : p_X(A)=0\}$, then $S=\bigcap_{A\in \mathcal A}\{ p : p(A)=0\}$ and \{ p:p(A)=0\} is closed since $p\to p(A)$ is a continuous linear functional. I must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: Yes, this was a typo. The continuity of $p \mapsto p(A)$ depends on the topology. It is continuous w.r.t. the total variation metric, but not w.r.t. the weak-* topology.

Comment: I don't understand this statement, The weak-* topology is a topology on $X^\ast$ if $X$ is the set of measures on $(\mathcal X,\Sigma_X)$. Then what does "a function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous wrt weak-* topology" means ? Now that I think of it I don't understand your second statement in the answer. Don't your weak-* topology match with my weak topology (i.e. the weakest topology that makes all strongly continuous linear functional on $X$ continuous), I think that would be my confusion if they are different in general.

Comment: No, we view measures as elements in the dual space of $C_0(\mathcal X)$. In particular, measures $p_k$ converge weak* to $p$ if $\int \varphi \, \mathrm d p_k \to \int \varphi \, \mathrm d p$ for all $\varphi \in C_0(\mathcal X)$.